# Combine unequal length audio and video on FFmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, audio, video, ffmpeg

My audio has a length of 200s while my video has a length of 14s.

Is there a way to extend the video to loop over itself to sustain for the duration of the audio length?

How do I then combine them into one video?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `-stream_loop` input option along with the `-shortest` output option.